# What would happen if a neutron star merged with a white dwarf?

Tags: star, supernova, neutron-star, white-dwarf, kilonova

We've heard of neutron star mergers and white dwarf mergers. But what would result in a neutron star merging with a white dwarf? Would there be a similar super/kilonova, are there any examples of it, and what would the remnant/merger be?

Comment: Closely related, if not a duplicate: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23198/2153